# What is Facebook application actual width

Tags: facebook, canvas, width

I am an facebook developer and today all my 760px wide facebook applications changed. It looks liek width is 1100 px approximately, but I cannot figure out any official facebook explanation for that ? Does anyone knows anything about this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Almost as wide as the browser window, if you build your app with Fluid Canvas. Which you should. https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/549.

The traditional size is 760 px. http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Canvas.setSize/

Comment: Ok, thank you very much... I see on blog that it requires some code editing... I will test it.....

Thanks again

Comment: user1034440, it would be polite and good site editcate to vote up and or accept the answer if it was correct or helped you in any way.